# how to provide safety to ionic source code

Tags: javascript, angular, security, ionic-framework, ionic4

hi it is always my question and worries about 
is ionic application secured? is that possible to crack the ionic app and get the inside code or sth like this for example if my code is like this(add a service to my app)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EncryptionService {

  url = 'https://api.amnas....com';
   api-key='......'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    newcheck(checkid: string ,cost: string,toname: string,tocode: string,passcode: string,date: string,checkfor: string,back: string): {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}?key=${this.api-key}&checkid=${encodeURI(checkid)}&cost=${encodeURI(cost)}&toname=${encodeURI(toname)}&tocode=${encodeURI(tocode)}&passcode=${encodeURI(passcode)}&date=${encodeURI(date)}&checkfor=${encodeURI(checkfor)}&back=${encodeURI(back)}`);
}


}
```

is that possible for anyone to crack my export app(apk) and extract api-key?

Comment: @brad will you please checkout this page too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142853/secured-connection-between-app-and-server

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you build your application, any security keys, tokens, etc., are accessible to the client.  You cannot rely on anything in your build remaining secret.

Comment: hi  thanks so what is the solution? the best way to connect to the api server?

Comment: @DAbasi Do it in a way where you don't automatically trust the request.  Does your API have some sort of user login?  Use that.

Comment: i will check for that tnx brad